# dynamicUpdate not working in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a customer table in which there are 3 columns i.e. id,name and age.

If I make a customer object with no age i.e. I don't set any age value, then in case if the same customer(identified by customer id) is present in the table, then saveOrUpdate() updates the age column to 0. I am looking to avoid the age column value to be overwritten by zero or null, if already present in the table.For e.g. as per the code snippet pasted below, if there is already a row exists for the customer id 10 with some age value, then in this case, my age should not be overwritten by zero.

I searched on google and found that I can set dynamicUpdate to true to achieve that. But on executing the code still my age value is overwritten by 0. I am pasting the code snippet

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
)
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private int custId;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_NAME")
    private String custName;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_AGE")
    private int custAge;
        ............
        ...........

       Customer cust = new Customer();
       cust.setCustId(10);
       cust.setCustName("anand");       
       session.saveOrUpdate(cust);      
       tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 4):

To let dynamicUpdate work, the get and update must be in the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

First: is better to use an `Integer` instead of an `int` as the type for custAge. This way you can make distinction between an empty and a valid 0 value.

Then, the `dynamicUpdate = true` is useful for what are you trying to do, but you also need to reattach the object to the session (in the update case). For example:

```
customer = session.get(Customer.class, id);
customer.set(...);
session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
```

Comment: but it also overwrites the value of age to null. I don't want the age value to be overwritten in case already present in the database..

Comment: I have changed the problem description. Do I make myself clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic update works only when first we fetch value by using session.get(...)
In this case suppose we have 10 columns and we want to update 5 columns then first we fetch object by using id then set new value into fetched object and it works fine
More we write coding only for 5 columns and if we update one column from that 5 column then by using dynamic update query fire as shown below

Hibernate: update usermaster set name=? where user_id=?

below is my code and here i chenged only name from front end

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tran = session.beginTransaction();
    Usermaster obj = (Usermaster) session.get(Usermaster.class,
            usermaster.getUserId());
    obj.setUsername(usermaster.getUsername());
    obj.setName(usermaster.getName());
    obj.setContact(usermaster.getContact());
    obj.setEmail(usermaster.getEmail());
    obj.setUserStatus(usermaster.getUserStatus());
    obj.setUserType(usermaster.getUserType());
    session.update(obj);
```